# Как написать специфичный для сценария setUp в случае использования библиотеки Behave?

Tags: python, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Мне хочется разобраться как использовать тест-конфигурацию созданную в методе помеченном декоратором `given` в других методах помеченных декораторами `when`, `then`.

Напомню, что методы декорируемые `given`, `then`, `when` реализуют так называемые `steps` в терминах библиотеки `behave`

Ранее использовал xUnit-фреймворки: `jUnit`, `unittest` и др. В каждом из них можно было осуществить настройку тест-среды непосредственно в тест-методе. Потому что в тест-методе можно было выполнить и `Arrange`, и `Act` и завершающий `Assert`. `Arrange-Act-Assert` - паттерн проектирования используемый в модульном тестировании.

Но как это сделать во фреймворке `Behave` у меня нет понимания. В нем же `Arrange` вынесен в метод помечаемый `given` декоратором, `Act` в метод `when`, а завершающи `Assert` в методе `then`.

Ссылка [Runner Operation](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#runner-operation) показывает как выглядит картина в целом, но не указывает на то как сделать специфично для одного сценария!

Возможно это следует сохранять в объекте [behave.runner.Context](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#behave.runner.Context)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Для моей задачи нужно использовать метод `given`, а информацию между работой методов `given`, `when`, `then` нужно сохранять и в объекте `context`. Об этом сказано в туториале [описание контекста](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#context).

```
It’s a clever place where you and behave can store information to share around. It runs at three levels, automatically managed by behave.
```